# Job submitting but map reduce not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I tried to run the example program present in Hadoop. However, I'm not successful in getting the output.

I have included my logs below. Please help in solving the issue.

```
hdfs@localhost:~$ hadoop jar '/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar' wordcount /README.txt /ooo
15/08/21 09:48:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8050
15/08/21 09:48:28 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/08/21 09:48:28 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/08/21 09:48:28 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1440130528838_0001
15/08/21 09:48:29 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1440130528838_0001
15/08/21 09:48:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1440130528838_0001/
15/08/21 09:48:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1440130528838_0001
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapreduce seems working, there is no error logs which appears.

```
1/ Can you please detail furthermore your logs?!
2/ Your output folder /ooo is created?? If yes what its contents?!
3/ Verify please if your input file is not empty.
```